# String format number with three sections as String.Format(“{0:$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00);Zero}”, value);

Tags: c#, number-formatting

I'm implementing string format number with three sections as

```
DataFormatString="{}{0:$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00);''}"
```

i.e:

```
input 120 result $120.00
input -120 result ($120.00)
input 0 result ''
```

the problem is the dollar sign is hard-coded and I want my app to globalization. I tried some thing like this:

```
DataFormatString="{}{0:C;C;''}"
```

but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps try taking this approach:

```
var DataFormatString="$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00);''";

var amount = 1342.56m;

var formatted =
    amount
        .ToString(DataFormatString)
        .Replace("$", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol);
```

The only downside is that it won't correctly place the currency symbol at the end of the number if that's the standard for that currency.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the overload of `string.Format` with `IFormatProvider` like so:

```
string DataFormatString="{0:C}";
string output = string.Format(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("culture"),DataFormatString,input)
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/BQJN6568)

However, as Soner Gonul observes, this still won't generate '' as output for 0.

Comment: Sadly, this _still_ generates `$0.00` for `0` :(

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no *direct* format to supply that 3 results you want for those inputs.

For first two format, you can use [The `"C"` format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#CFormatString) with `en-US` culture (which has `$` as a [`CurrencySymbol`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencysymbol.aspx)) using `2` as a precision specifier like;

```
(120).ToString("C2", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))  // $120.00
(-120).ToString("C2", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")) // ($120.00)
```

But for `0`, this generates `$0.00` which is not what you want.

As a better solution, check [Enigmativity's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34627669/447156) instead which handles `0` value as well.